# Google Fonts API for C# - System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, access-violation, google-api-dotnet-client, google-font-api

I'm trying to do a call to the Google API Services (specifically Google.Apis.Webfonts.v1.WebfontsService) from a C# console application. And each time i'm getting the very same exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

My complete test application code is below and the google api is added as NuGet packages. I'm using the latest version of the API NuGet packages and i'm targeting .Net 4.5 on windows 8.1 and VS2013 sp4:

```
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Webfonts.v1;
using Google.Apis.Webfonts.v1.Data;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create the service
            var service = new WebfontsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "Webfonts Sample",
                ApiKey = "my private api key",
            });

            // run the request 
            var result = service.Webfonts.List().Execute();

            // display the results
            if (result.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (Webfont font in result.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(font.Family);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same problem exist for any API call to Google.Apis. So this made me think it's not directly related to the Webfonts, but to the BaseClientService.
I tried to solve it by running it in 32bit mode, but this didn't help me. Next, instead of nuget packages i used the source version of the api and tried to debug it. So i got to the point where the exception is thrown, but still can't see how it's been generated.

Did anybody encounter this problem before and able to resole it. And how?

UPDATE: the same code runs fine on other boxes with the same setup.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it and it worked fine for me.

You need the following NuGet Packages.

> Install-Package Google.Apis.Webfonts.v1 
>    Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth

**Usings**

```
using Google.Apis.Webfonts.v1;
using Google.Apis.Webfonts.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
```

**Auth**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Used for accessing public api data. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="apiKey">Public API key from Google Developers console</param>
    /// <returns>a valid WebfontsService</returns>
    public static WebfontsService AuthenticatePublic(string apiKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey))
            throw new Exception("apiKey is required.");
        try
        {
            // Create the service.
            var service = new WebfontsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = apiKey,
                ApplicationName = "Webfonts Authentication Sample",
            });
            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**Request Method**

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the list of fonts currently served by the Google Fonts Developer API
/// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api/v1/webfonts/list
/// </summary>
/// <param name="service">Valid authentcated WebfontsService</param>
 /// <returns></returns>
 public static WebfontList list(WebfontsService service)
 {
  try
    {
        var request = service.Webfonts.List();
  return  request.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request Failed " + ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }


 }
```

**Putting it all together**

```
 var service =  StandardGoogleAuth.AuthenticatePublic("Your Public API key");

            var result = WebfontsSample.list(service);

            if (result.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (var font in result.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(font.Family);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for you time, but this is basically the same example i provided in my question.

Comment: Probably and it works fine.  Check your api key maybe.   There is no issue with the client library or the api

Comment: I updated my question. My code runs fine on some other boxes under the same IP. I have no restrictions on my api key. Thanks anyway!